# Referring to a Clojure generated class from AOT compilation?

Tags: clojure

This code does not compile with `lein compile`. The important parts are the `gen-class` and `-main` function. The code uses JavaFX 8 and Clojure 1.7, but these are just particulars. My question is about AOT compilation and how to refer to a generated class.

```lisp
(ns the.app
  (:import
   [javafx.application Application]
   [javafx.scene Scene]
   [javafx.scene.layout StackPane]
   [javafx.stage Stage])
  (:gen-class
   :name the.app.App
   :extends javafx.application.Application
   :main true))

(defn start
  [^Application app
   ^Stage stage
   {:keys [width height title] :as opts}]
  (let [root (StackPane.)
        scene (Scene. root width height)]
    (if title (.setTitle stage title))
    (.setScene stage scene)
    (.show stage)))

(defn -start
  [app stage]
  (start app stage {:title "App" :width 800 :height 600}))

(defn -stop
  [app]
  (println "-stop"))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (Application/launch the.app.App args))
```

My `project.clj` contains:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0-alpha4"]]
:aot [the.app]
:main the.app
```

The error message is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: the.app.App
```

I would have thought that compiling would create `the.app.App`. How can I solve the problem of referring to a class [compiled from AOT](http://clojure.org/compilation)?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that using [`resolve`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/resolve) works (instead of referring to the class directly):

```lisp
(defn -main
  [& args]
  (Application/launch (resolve 'the.app.App) args))
```

This means that `the.app.App` does not have to exist when the `defn` form is [evaluated](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/eval). The class only needs to exist at runtime, which will happen after AOT compilation.